# Multiple Selection in Cocoa's NSTableView without Command Key

Tags: cocoa, nstableview

Is there any way to achieve multiple selection behavior in an NSTableView without requiring the user to hold down the command button while clicking?  This was easy to do in a Carbon list box, by ORing in the cmdKey modifier flag, during mouse down processing, on the call to the HandleControlClick() function.  I am new to Cocoa, and it is not clear to me how I can easily modify an event programmatically, or if this is the best solution.

Comment: Have you considered adding a checkbox column to your table view so that it's clear to your users how to select multiple items? I worry that overriding the default click behavior will confuse and irritate them. For example, how do they deselect all items?

Comment: Alex, I definitely agree in general.  In this specific case it works well, given some other affordances in the Window.

Answer (score 4):

Subclass NSTableView and make your table view an instance of this subclass. In the subclass, respond to both `mouseDown:` and `mouseUp:` by creating a new mouse event based on the one you received, only with the `NSCommandKeyMask` flag ORed into the modifier flags, and passing the new event up to `super`.

However, I hope it will be obvious to your user that they can select multiple items. Also, don't break the Shift key—make sure contiguous selection still works.

Comment: Thanks Peter!  I ended up responding to mouseDown in the subclass, creating a new mouseDown event based on the one received, and ORing in the NSCommandKeyMask based on whether the NSShiftKeyMask was set.  It works just great.

Comment: Er, yeah. Mouse is what I meant, not key. I've edited my answer accordingly.